# If - Else statement and element style in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and I am trying to change two elements' style

The first one to make `display:none` and another element takes `opacity:1`

When my third element style is changing. Here is my code but it does not work.

What is the reason?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if ($(".about").css("width") == "100%") { 
       $('.logo').css({"display":"none"});
       $('.headerleftpart img').css({"opacity":"1"});
   }
   else {
       $('.logo').css({"display":"block"});
       $('.headerleftpart img').css({"opacity":"0"});
  }
});
```

Comment: Post a working jsfiddle with the problem

Comment: Wow this question is a sh**storm of edits.

Comment: The reason is: You haven't implemented the part `when my third element style is changing`. Currently you only check the third element`s width once, after DOM ready

Comment: why on document.ready? do you want to do it on $(window).resize() ??

Comment: remove % from if condition

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: I removed % but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rg0h6met/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var width = $('.about').width();
var parentWidth = $('.about').offsetParent().width();
var percent = 100*width/parentWidth;
console.log(percent);
if (percent == "100") {
    $('.logo').css({
        "display": "none"
    });
    $('.headerleftpart img').css({
        "opacity": "1"
    });
} else {
    $('.logo').css({
        "display": "block"
    });
    $('.headerleftpart img').css({
        "opacity": "0"
    });
}
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="about" style="width:100%">
   <div class="logo">Logo</div>
   <div class="headerleftpart"><img src='http://adaptive-images.com/content/images/creepy.jpg'/ style='height:150px;widht:150px;'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort to help me but there is no difference.I copied and pasted your code into my code.

Comment: have you looked my html properly there is no image tag please change accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

You're using `$(document).ready` which means that your code is executed only once.

If you always want to change style when element has been resized, you should use `$(".about").resize`.

See [jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/resize/).